# Pandas - Sum occurrences of string in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Supposing that I have a DataFrame along the lines of:

|  | David | Maxime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | cat | duck |
| 1 | dog | cat |
| 2 | horse | duck |
| 3 | cat | dog |

How to obtain the following result ?

| Animals | Total |
| --- | --- |
| cat | 3 |
| duck | 2 |
| dog | 2 |
| horse | 1 |

I found many codes but not for the case where a result is return according to number of occurrences of datas in unique column.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
pd.concat([df.David.value_counts(), df.Maxine.value_counts()], axis=1).fillna(0).sum(axis=1)
```

This creates a dataframe with the value counts along each column, then sums the rows.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to melt the dataframe, and use value_counts:

```py
(df.melt(value_name = 'Animal')
   .value_counts(subset='Animal')
   .reset_index(name='Total')
)
  Animal  Total
0    cat      3
1    dog      2
2   duck      2
3  horse      1
```